# How do I increment counter field by 1 using UpdateCommand

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to make a rate limiter and I'm having trouble finding documentation on `UpdateCommand`. Right now I'm trying to increment the counter field by 1 everytime I make a request with the same ip address.

[image]
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/classes/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.updatecommand-1.html

Here is what I tried

```js
const command = new UpdateCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
        ipAddr: sourceIp
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set counter = Add :counter counter",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":counter": 1,
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
});
```

Comment: It may be useful to you:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD

Comment: FWIW -- DynamoDB may not be the best way to implement a rate limiter (unless your rate limits are extremely low and you don't have that many customers to begin with)

Comment: Whats the better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be it:

```js
const command = new UpdateCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
        ipAddr: sourceIp
    },
    UpdateExpression: "ADD counter :counter",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":counter": 1,
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
});
```